# SQL with string concatenation is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-optimization

I have a stored procedure which is taking 15 seconds to execute. The database is SQL Server 2008 R2.

The SQL query is as follows,

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeSetA
    UNION 
SELECT * FROM EmployeeSetB
WHERE
Name+''+Id NOT IN (SELECT Name+''+Id FROM EmployeeSetA)
```

The query is trying to union EmployeeSetA and EmployeeSetB and also ensures that Name and Id in EmployeeSetB is not in EmployeeSetA before performing Union.

When I verified, the string concatenation is causing the SQL to run slowly. Is there any better approach? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: changed to `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM EmployeeSetA A WHERE A.Name = EmployeeSetB.Name AND A.Id = EmployeeSetB.Id )`

Comment: Are you sure it's the string concatenation? `UNION` does `DISTINCT`, which usually does an `ORDER BY` which is an expensive operation, especially over strings.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, in the above SQL, I did not see slowness with union. I concluded that string concatenation is causing slowness by changing the SQL as shown below,
WHERE
Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM EmployeeSetA)
When I removed the string concatenation and just verified with one column, it executed in 1 second. If you have a better approach/solution, please advise.

Comment: OK that's good that you've isolated the issue. I agree with @Squirrel - try his solution first.

Comment: @PhilCoulson, could you please provide an example on how to do it?

Comment: Without an execution plan and details of indexing, we cannot advise further, we're just guessing in the dark

Comment: At a guess might be worth trying `union all` and adding a fixed column `1` for EmployeeSetA and `2` for EmployeeSetB then use `DENSE_RANK` across that column and pick `dr=1`

Comment: @Squirrel I have implemented your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could stack the two tables first and then use `except` to get rid of unwanted records. Feel free to change `union all` to `union` if that's what you actually want. Having said that, `not exists` is the ideal solution

```
select * from EmployeeSetA
union all
select * from EmployeeSetB
except 
select b.* from EmployeeSetB b
join EmployeeSetA a on a.name=b.name and a.id=b.id;
```

Or more directly,

```
select * from EmployeeSetA
union all
select b.* from EmployeeSetB b
left join EmployeeSetA a on a.name=b.name and a.id=b.id
where a.name is null or a.id is null;
```